# add geojson to a leaflet map through the django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, leaflet, geojson

I have a django view that takes the results of a SQL query and renders it to the index.html home page of my web map. the POST request correctly returns the acreage of the SQL query to the page. Additionally I am trying return the geojson of the SQL query to on a leaflet map. I am choosing to return it through the django template as opposed to a JSONResponse because I was having a hard time figuring out how to return both the rendering of the acreage to HTML and the JSONResponse

here is html document, I included only the relevant JavaScript.

```
<html>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load geojson_tags %}
<head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}

    <title>Our Home</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #gis {width: 80%;height:900px;}
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'leaflet-search-master/src/leaflet-search.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'leafletgroupedlayercontrol/dist/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'routing/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'leaflet-control-osm-geocoder-master/Control.OSMGeocoder.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree-master/L.Control.Layers.Tree.css' %}">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'turf/turf.min.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'leaflet-search-master/src/leaflet-search.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'leafletgroupedlayercontrol/dist/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'leaflet-control-osm-geocoder-master/Control.OSMGeocoder.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree-master/L.Control.Layers.Tree.js' %}" > </script>

</head>
<body>
<br>
<div id="parcel search" class="col-md-2 well">
    <h3><b>Parcel Search</b></h3>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.ssn }}
        {{ form.block }}
        {{ form.lot }}
        <br>
        <button name="submit_form" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h5>Open Water Acres = {{ text }}</h5>
    <br>
    <h3><b>Legend</b></h3>
        stuff
        <button id="Planning_Preservation" class="form-control btn-success">Planning Preservation</button>
</div>

{% block content %}
<!-- <script src="{% static 'js.js' %}"></script> -->


<script type="text/javascript">
function our_layers(map,options){

        map.setView([40.79406,-74.666], 10);

        //javascript...
        //javascript...

    console.log("hey there")
    var blah= "{{ data }}"
    console.log(blah)
    var intersection = new L.geoJSON(blah).addTo(map);
};    

</script>

{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}

{% endblock %}

<div id="footer" class="col-md-12">
    <h4 id="map_coords" class="text-center">Latitude: 40 Longitude: -75.00 Zoom Level: 11
    </h4>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

now my views.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    text=""
    row=None
    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        #posts = Post.objects.all()

        #args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            qry = '''with inter as(SELECT st_union(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom)) geom,
                            round((sum(st_area(st_intersection(st_transform(a.geom,3424),st_transform(b.geom,3424))))/43560)::numeric,2)  open_water_acres,
                        hl_parce_1 ssn, hl_parce_2 block, hl_parce_3 lot
                        from reporter_parcels a join reporter_open_waters b
                        on st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
                        where hl_parce_1 = '{}' and hl_parce_2 = '{}' and hl_parce_3 = '{}'
                        group by hl_parce_1, hl_parce_2, hl_parce_3
                        )

                        SELECT row_to_json(fc)
                              FROM
                               ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS TYPE,
                                       array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features
                               FROM
                                 (SELECT 'Feature' AS TYPE,
                                         ST_AsGeoJSON(g.geom)::JSON AS geometry,            
                                         row_to_json((SELECT p
                                                        FROM
                                                          ( SELECT geom,open_water_acres,ssn,block,lot) AS p)) AS properties
                                  FROM inter AS g
                                  ) AS f) AS fc
                        '''.format(str(form.cleaned_data['ssn']), str(form.cleaned_data['block']),
                                   str(form.cleaned_data['lot']))
            cur.execute(qry)
            self.row=cur.fetchone()
            print(self.row[0])
            geom=json.dumps(self.row[0])
            print(geom)
            self.text = [x['features'][0]['properties']['open_water_acres'] for x in self.row][0]
        args = {'form': form, 'text': self.text, 'data': geom}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

the ssn block and lot are submitted through a django form. the query runs correctly and returns the acreage to the map but the geoJSON does not get displayed and throws this error

```
leaflet.js:8 Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.
    at Function.geometryToLayer (leaflet.js:8)
    at e.addData (leaflet.js:8)
    at e.initialize (leaflet.js:8)
    at new e (leaflet.js:5)
    at new o.geoJSON (leaflet.js:8)
    at Object.our_layers [as callback] ((index):313)
    at Function.L.Map.djangoMap (leaflet.extras.js:234)
    at loadmap ((index):331)
```

I take away the quotes around "{{ data }}" and have `{{ data }}`
 it gives me back `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

this is the geojson that gets returned

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-74.6739518440393, 40.7747050657312], [-74.6739608984706, 40.774701470443], [-74.6739723349471, 40.7746977607907], [-74.6739751675288, 40.7746968784469], [-74.6739837541201, 40.7746942303805], [-74.6739935481257, 40.7746907699636], [-74.6740013899782, 40.7746860093379], [-74.6740073655541, 40.7746788091302], [-74.6740121265096, 40.7746701139759], [-74.6740163465814, 40.7746611584664], [-74.674020565505, 40.7746522173678], [-74.6740252548045, 40.7746433025775], [-74.6740306482882, 40.7746345794509], [-74.674037125077, 40.7746260600244], [-74.67404531627, 40.7746171669696], [-74.674055546289, 40.7746073801574], [-74.6740664962855, 40.7745970284899], [-74.6740765608797, 40.7745864998405], [-74.6740844217022, 40.7745753981381], [-74.6740891740435, 40.7745634095419], [-74.6740912184884, 40.7745510530875], [-74.6740912522389, 40.7745431062451], [-74.6740912592608, 40.7745389887446], [-74.6740898573801, 40.7745274759369], [-74.6740874080518, 40.774516334851], [-74.6740842350919, 40.7745039052142], [-74.6740806379698, 40.7744887303232], [-74.6740772899942, 40.7744718808624], [-74.6740745918208, 40.7744548115784], [-74.6740716598383, 40.7744380299347], [-74.6740677904043, 40.7744220052984], [-74.6740641056594, 40.7744077509401], [-74.6740617274588, 40.7743957172631], [-74.6740596382422, 40.7743836561325], [-74.6740567313083, 40.7743696608708], [-74.6740535362175, 40.7743560091677], [-74.6740507803652, 40.7743449784148], [-74.6740486411357, 40.7743346329802], [-74.674046876481, 40.7743225578509], [-74.6740443488904, 40.7743086583796], [-74.6740400676368, 40.7742937042621], [-74.6740344161057, 40.7742797959928], [-74.6740280856495, 40.7742685643951], [-74.6740213071077, 40.7742585834894], [-74.6740142574633, 40.7742482175403], [-74.6740073704415, 40.7742379756267], [-74.6740010091114, 40.7742285290402], [-74.6739952617479, 40.7742192040077], [-74.6739901073244, 40.7742092062419], [-74.6739855487456, 40.7741987410728], [-74.6739818030118, 40.7741883431228], [-74.6739798635669, 40.7741787385697], [-74.6739807816149, 40.7741705436324], [-74.6739848612134, 40.7741636065536], [-74.6739918323364, 40.7741575017619], [-74.6739997064445, 40.7741515063806], [-74.6740066038684, 40.7741448523401], [-74.6740127217719, 40.7741368278785], [-74.6740186544125, 40.7741272663915], [-74.6740243888565, 40.7741180213096], [-74.6740300024878, 40.7741106010017], [-74.674036843766, 40.7741033166322], [-74.6740459920852, 40.7740944221332], [-74.6740562774083, 40.7740854304562], [-74.6740660622271, 40.7740780317735], [-74.6740738262204, 40.7740716105748], [-74.6740786122417, 40.7740652767219], [-74.6740812323746, 40.7740592604413], [-74.6740825371966, 40.7740540161479], [-74.6740814060334, 40.7740495437309], [-74.6740768280652, 40.7740457213346], [-74.6740701215455, 40.774042450607], [-74.6740628024946, 40.7740396067813], [-74.6740551952523, 40.7740370930051], [-74.674047317158, 40.7740347444446], [-74.6740391506585, 40.7740321900838], [-74.6740306926327, 40.7740291417389], [-74.6740219467778, 40.7740261082369], [-74.674012949883, 40.7740235686352], [-74.6740039703984, 40.7740213451131], [-74.6739951722373, 40.7740191492351], [-74.6739863735011, 40.7740167327132], [-74.6739774654974, 40.7740137543881], [-74.6739689684304, 40.7740093615191], [-74.6739646797748, 40.7740056350451], [-74.6739616579912, 40.7740030035779], [-74.6739563321926, 40.7739958753433], [-74.6739538776307, 40.7739895244913], [-74.6739536210559, 40.7739810836627], [-74.6739556885068, 40.7739707318847], [-74.6739589081517, 40.7739592940613], [-74.6739623458013, 40.773948322414], [-74.6739659288001, 40.773937666654], [-74.6739697830071, 40.7739269825668], [-74.6739740897417, 40.7739167507932], [-74.673978381855, 40.7739081806272], [-74.6739833924052, 40.7738980027281], [-74.6739871398759, 40.773888183366], [-74.676322372932, 40.7763416608939], [-74.6763156261991, 40.7763638597837], [-74.6762951846018, 40.7764154586843], [-74.6762703483574, 40.7764659313537], [-74.6762568620317, 40.776489749991], [-74.6762243927602, 40.7765446994232], [-74.6762087518394, 40.7765700100167], [-74.6761796366478, 40.7766116193076], [-74.6761800802631, 40.7766127209501], [-74.6761963152469, 40.7766651770285], [-74.676208002871, 40.7767183271962], [-74.6762084403033, 40.7767212849423], [-74.676152056193, 40.7767557149623], [-74.676046211745, 40.7768210835496], [-74.6759487072312, 40.7768796732066], [-74.6739755084356, 40.7747308337148], [-74.6739518440393, 40.7747050657312]]]}, "properties": {"geom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open_water_acres": 4.45, "ssn": "1407", "block": "10", "lot": "92"}}]}
```

when I console.log the data from

`var raw_data='{{ data }}'`

I get back

```
{&quot;type&quot;: &quot;FeatureCollection&quot;, &quot;features&quot;: [{&quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;, &quot;geometry&quot;: {&quot;type&quot;: &quot;Polygon&quot;, &quot;coordinates&quot;: [[[-74.6739518440393, 40.7747050657312], [-74.6739608984706, 40.774701470443], [-74.6739723349471, 40.7746977607907], [-74.6739751675288, 40.7746968784469], [-74.6739837541201, 40.7746942303805], [-74.6739935481257, 40.7746907699636], [-74.6740013899782, 40.7746860093379], [-74.6740073655541, 40.7746788091302], [-74.6740121265096, 40.7746701139759], [-74.6740163465814, 40.7746611584664], [-74.674020565505, 40.7746522173678], [-74.6740252548045, 40.7746433025775], [-74.6740306482882, 40.7746345794509], [-74.674037125077, 40.7746260600244], [-74.67404531627, 40.7746171669696], [-74.674055546289, 40.7746073801574], [-74.6740664962855, 40.7745970284899], [-74.6740765608797, 40.7745864998405], [-74.6740844217022, 40.7745753981381], [-74.6740891740435, 40.7745634095419], [-74.6740912184884, 40.7745510530875], [-74.6740912522389, 40.7745431062451], [-74.6740912592608, 40.7745389887446], [-74.6740898573801, 40.7745274759369], [-74.6740874080518, 40.774516334851], [-74.6740842350919, 40.7745039052142], [-74.6740806379698, 40.7744887303232], [-74.6740772899942, 40.7744718808624], [-74.6740745918208, 40.7744548115784], [-74.6740716598383, 40.7744380299347], [-74.6740677904043, 40.7744220052984], [-74.6740641056594, 40.7744077509401], [-74.6740617274588, 40.7743957172631], [-74.6740596382422, 40.7743836561325], [-74.6740567313083, 40.7743696608708], [-74.6740535362175, 40.7743560091677], [-74.6740507803652, 40.7743449784148], [-74.6740486411357, 40.7743346329802], [-74.674046876481, 40.7743225578509], [-74.6740443488904, 40.7743086583796], [-74.6740400676368, 40.7742937042621], [-74.6740344161057, 40.7742797959928], [-74.6740280856495, 40.7742685643951], [-74.6740213071077, 40.7742585834894], [-74.6740142574633, 40.7742482175403], [-74.6740073704415, 40.7742379756267], [-74.6740010091114, 40.7742285290402], [-74.6739952617479, 40.7742192040077], [-74.6739901073244, 40.7742092062419], [-74.6739855487456, 40.7741987410728], [-74.6739818030118, 40.7741883431228], [-74.6739798635669, 40.7741787385697], [-74.6739807816149, 40.7741705436324], [-74.6739848612134, 40.7741636065536], [-74.6739918323364, 40.7741575017619], [-74.6739997064445, 40.7741515063806], [-74.6740066038684, 40.7741448523401], [-74.6740127217719, 40.7741368278785], [-74.6740186544125, 40.7741272663915], [-74.6740243888565, 40.7741180213096], [-74.6740300024878, 40.7741106010017], [-74.674036843766, 40.7741033166322], [-74.6740459920852, 40.7740944221332], [-74.6740562774083, 40.7740854304562], [-74.6740660622271, 40.7740780317735], [-74.6740738262204, 40.7740716105748], [-74.6740786122417, 40.7740652767219], [-74.6740812323746, 40.7740592604413], [-74.6740825371966, 40.7740540161479], [-74.6740814060334, 40.7740495437309], [-74.6740768280652, 40.7740457213346], [-74.6740701215455, 40.774042450607], [-74.6740628024946, 40.7740396067813], [-74.6740551952523, 40.7740370930051], [-74.674047317158, 40.7740347444446], [-74.6740391506585, 40.7740321900838], [-74.6740306926327, 40.7740291417389], [-74.6740219467778, 40.7740261082369], [-74.674012949883, 40.7740235686352], [-74.6740039703984, 40.7740213451131], [-74.6739951722373, 40.7740191492351], [-74.6739863735011, 40.7740167327132], [-74.6739774654974, 40.7740137543881], [-74.6739689684304, 40.7740093615191], [-74.6739646797748, 40.7740056350451], [-74.6739616579912, 40.7740030035779], [-74.6739563321926, 40.7739958753433], [-74.6739538776307, 40.7739895244913], [-74.6739536210559, 40.7739810836627], [-74.6739556885068, 40.7739707318847], [-74.6739589081517, 40.7739592940613], [-74.6739623458013, 40.773948322414], [-74.6739659288001, 40.773937666654], [-74.6739697830071, 40.7739269825668], [-74.6739740897417, 40.7739167507932], [-74.673978381855, 40.7739081806272], [-74.6739833924052, 40.7738980027281], [-74.6739871398759, 40.773888183366], [-74.676322372932, 40.7763416608939], [-74.6763156261991, 40.7763638597837], [-74.6762951846018, 40.7764154586843], [-74.6762703483574, 40.7764659313537], [-74.6762568620317, 40.776489749991], [-74.6762243927602, 40.7765446994232], [-74.6762087518394, 40.7765700100167], [-74.6761796366478, 40.7766116193076], [-74.6761800802631, 40.7766127209501], [-74.6761963152469, 40.7766651770285], [-74.676208002871, 40.7767183271962], [-74.6762084403033, 40.7767212849423], [-74.676152056193, 40.7767557149623], [-74.676046211745, 40.7768210835496], [-74.6759487072312, 40.7768796732066], [-74.6739755084356, 40.7747308337148], [-74.6739518440393, 40.7747050657312]]]}, &quot;properties&quot;: {&quot;geom&quot;: &quot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quot;, &quot;open_water_acres&quot;: 4.45, &quot;ssn&quot;: &quot;1407&quot;, &quot;block&quot;: &quot;10&quot;, &quot;lot&quot;: &quot;92&quot;}}]}
```

Comment: It would be useful to know what is actually being rendered in the HTML.  Are you sure `data` is properly formatted JSON?

Comment: Also - not related to your question but it's dangerous to send user-provided data directly to SQL, you open yourself up to an SQL injection attack.  You *might* be fine depending on what you are doing to clean the form data, but it would be fairly trivial to accidentally disable one of the form data cleaning functions somewhere down the line.  Instead of using `.format` you should use the `params` argument to `cursor.execute`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly   You also should remove the quotes around those placeholders (turn `'{}'` into `%s`)

Comment: @Dave I will upload my JSON to the question as soon as I have time

Comment: @Dave added my geojson and point taken about SQL injection -- I am just in the learning phase of all of this so its just for testing purposes and seeing how everything interacts together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting ampersands (&) in your JSON because Django is trying to be helpful.  By default, for security, all data passed to templates is [HTML-escaped](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#escape).

This is done so that a malicious user can't fill out a form with something like `"><a href="http://my.evil.site/">Look at this cool page</a>` which when rendered on your site would trick other users to going to the 'evil site'.

So, you shouldn't turn it off.  Instead, use the Django template filter [escapejs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs), which in essence tells Django to make the data safe for Javascript instead of for HTML.

Also, for security and maintainability, you should always quote the data and then use javascript to parse it into JSON.  So don't just do `var data = {{data|escapejs}};`

What you want to do is to use single quotes to pass the data in as a string, and then use javascript to parse the string into a js object:

```
var raw_data = '{{data|escapejs}}';
var data = JSON.parse(raw_data);
```

Comment: `VM103:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.our_layers [as callback] ((index):308)
    at Function.L.Map.djangoMap (leaflet.extras.js:234)
    at loadmap ((index):328)` with your suggestion. the thing is Dave its valid geojson. if you take the geojson I provided and create a file and add it qgis it displays correctly...

Comment: updated the output of the JSON that gets rendered to html

Comment: Ah yes I see, you can tell it's been a little while since I've done this :)  Updated my answer.